# Triggering an oracle job based completion of the procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Scenario: I have 77 procedures, each for one data file which will load it into tables. Once the complete set of 77 procedures completes The transformation job should start which will push the data to downstream.

One way is to create flag value once a procedure completes and exits and store on the table and based on query on the table and a condition to trigger that job. But this approach needs lot of code changes and it's not advised.

Please suggest me some DBA tables like `v$session` or `dba_procedures` on which I can put condition which will depict the running and completion of the procedure and can `trigger` that job. Or suggest some other idea.

Comment: Why don't you call the 77 procedures and then the transformation in a script or procedure?

Comment: you haven't mentioned the version and whether you use regular jobs or scheduler jobs. for regular jobs the dictionary table is `all_jobs` and for scheduler jobs it's `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS`. Plus, i suggest reading about chains.

Answer (score 0):

"Once the complete set of 77 procedures completes **[SUCCESSFULLY]** The transformation job should start which will push the data to downstream."

I added what I think is a missing, but crucial keyword there.  When it comes to determining whether a given piece of application code has completed successfully, yes, you can probably write some convoluted logic that detects that each process (1) has been running in the recent past and (2) is no longer running right now.  But I wouldn't recommend this, as it completely overlooks checking that your load jobs finished successfully.

I'd suggest a proactive, rather than reactive design: write one central point of code from which all of these processes are submitted, monitored, and return-code checked. The "correct" way to implement this will depend on how your application currently schedules and runs these load procedures.  If you have a "design-by-clone" application (i.e. each of 77 files is loaded with independent script that is cron-scheduled and runs sqlldr utility for 1 file), and you do not want to modify these 77 files, then a simple DIY approach might be to cron-schedule a single "master" script that:

1) Submits all 77 loading procedure as background processes - retaining process id in an array
2) Loops through array, waits on each process, and checks return code
3) Submits "post-77-loading" process when #2 completes

Basic implementation of above idea:

```
#! bash
load_script1.sh &
processes[1]=$?
load_script2.sh &
processes[2]=$?
...
load_script77.sh &
processes[77]=$?

for (( c=1; c<77; c++))
do
    wait ${processes[c]}
    if [ $? -gt 0 ] ; then echo "At least one load job failed!" ; exit 1 ; fi
done
run_after_77_loads.sh
```

Of course, if you're using something other than cron, e.g. DBMS_SCHEDULER, you'll want to write something that's capable of checking return codes of each job in that context.

Comment: Thanks, all 77 procedure are scheduled via sys.dbms_job.isubmit and the unix script is scheduled on autosys in HP-UX land scape.

Comment: In detail: Thanks Kevin, all 77 procedure is scheduled via sys.dbms_job.iSubmit and the unix script is scheduled on autosys in HP-UX land scape. So we can't schedule the 77 procedure through load_script1. sh and so on. Any other solution will be highly helpful. Any table which holds procedure run time related info will be very handy.